# Google spreadsheet : conditional format to check if the formula in the cell contains specific syntax

Tags: google-sheets

Can i check if the formula in the cell contains specific syntax ?

for example :

I want to use conditional formatting , so if the formula in the cell contains the syntax `"if($B$6="`, i want to make the font color to red.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`FORMULATEXT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365792?hl=en) to convert the formula into a string, so custom formula is:

```
=isnumber(SEARCH("if($B$6=",formulatext(A2)))
```

[image]

Font colour can be done the same way.

[image]